# IIS 7.5 - Redirect webpage or default page

Tags: web-server, iis-7

I have a website like so:  http://website.com/path/default.html

If I go to http://website.com  I get the IIS 7 Welcome screen.  If I go to http://website.com I would like to be redirected to http://website.com/path/default.html

How do I go about this in IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a 301 redirect using your language of choice?

Comment: Maybe it's not called a redirect.  My website is located here: http://website.com/path/default.html , but when users go to http://website.com all they get is the IIS 7 welcome screen.  I would like them to get the http://website.com/path/default.html instead.  How do I do this in IIS 7 ??

Comment: Dan was right.  I had to go to IIS manager > Hostname of my server > Sites > Default Web Site > choose HTTP Redirect > check Redirect requests to this destination: http://website.com/path/default.html then Check Redirect all requests to exact destintation and check Only redirect requests to content in this directory.  Now it works perfectly.